# Does a dish received as a gift from another Jew need to be toveled?

Tags: halacha, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, tevilas-keilim-dipping, gifts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tevilat Keilim on a gift](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14213/tevilat-keilim-on-a-gift)

If I buy Ploni a new coffee mug, does he need to tovel it?  Did I need to tovel it?

Comment: Tagging help appreciated.

Comment: Was the dish manufactured by a Jew?

Comment: If it was ever owned by a non-Jew (including during manufacture), it needs to be Toveled. Any Jew can do it between the last gentile owner in the supply chain and the Jewish owner at the end.

Comment: @GershonGold presumably not - am I mistakenly thinking that the basis for tevilas keilim is non-Jewish *ownership*?

Comment: Duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14213 unless I'm missing something; see also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15523. Closing as duplicate.

Comment: No, definitely a duplicate - that aside, it's worth mentioning that a coffee mug usually [doesn't need tevilah](http://www.kof-k.org/articles/040108090413W-3%20Tevilas%20Keilim.pdf).

Comment: @yoel, if I'm not mistaken (and I may be), most coffee mugs are made with a glaze. See the bullet point about glazes in that document you linked.